# Graphics beginBitmapFill easeljs

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, bitmap, easeljs

I want to show shapes like this example: http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/game

I want to load the shapes filled with in image.
This is what I do:

```
var img = "<img src='http://nielsvroman.be/twitter/root/easeljs/image.png'>";

//setup
this.graphics.clear();
this.graphics.beginStroke("#FFFFFF");
this.graphics.beginBitmapFill(img); 
this.graphics.moveTo(0, size);
```

But I continuously get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Type error

This error is created in Graphic.js :
[image]

The document: http://nielsvroman.be/twitter/root/game.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty obvious, you pass a string and not an Image (HTMLImageElement).

Try:

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = 'image1.png';
```

or

```
var img1 = document.createElement('img')
img2.src = 'image2.jpg';
```